# Override a winforms OnLoad leads to error creating handler error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on an application that has hundreds of Forms and forms are linked with each in number of ways.

What the problem is i want to apply authentication to forms.

What i did is inherit all forms from a common class in my case it is "**AUTH**"

In Auth what i did is Override OnLoad method and here check if some condition is satisfied then Show the form else Hide it and show some other form.

My code is:

```
public class Auth : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (<Some Condition>)
        {
            base.Hide();

            frmAccessDenied fs = new frmAccessDenied();

            fs.Show();

            base.OnLoad(e);

        }
        else
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

    }

}
```

What happened in this case is it open the frmAccessDenied but the application crashes saying **Error Creating HANDLER**

and points to where i am opening the form like

```
                                        Form childForm = new frmMyFORM();
                                        childForm.MdiParent = this;
       **==>>>Crashed HERE**            childForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MDI Parent is the bug.

```
 Form childForm = new frmMyFORM();
                                    childForm.MdiParent = this;
   **==>>>Crashed HERE**            childForm.Show();
```

If i skip the code

```
childForm.MdiParent = this;
```

then everthing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition in your main program file. In the Main method, you will have something like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Starts the application.
    if (<Some Condition>)
    {
        Application.Run(new frmAccessDenied());
    }
    else Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: I need to apply authorization for each and every from. For example we open form1 and then from form1 we will be opening form2 in this case i dont think Main function will be called